# import URL from row in csv for beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am looking to import the URL from rows in file.csv so beautiful soup can parse the XML, but I have no idea how to make the following occur.

```html
url = row in 'file.csv'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('url').read()

letters = soup.select('h1')

print letters
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read from a csv file?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [built-in `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
import urllib2

with open("input.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        url = row[0]

        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
        letters = soup.select('h1')
        print url, letters
```

This code would work as is if you have existing `input.csv` file where you have a URL in the first "cell" of every row, for example:

```
https://google.com,some_other_data,1
https://stackoverflow.com,some_other_data,1
```